# Running into SMTP error when trying to send email in RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, gmail

I've been desperately trying to send an email using the Action Mailer class in RoR, and even though the terminal shows that a message is being sent, it keeps returning with this error:

```
 et::SMTPAuthenticationError: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtOS

from /Users/abhasarya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:968:in `check_auth_response'
from /Users/abhasarya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:739:in `auth_plain'
from /Users/abhasarya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:731:in `authenticate'...
```

Here's what my mailer class looks like within app/mailers/my_mailer.rb:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def welcome_email(user) 
    @user = user

        mail(to: user.email,
             from: 'example_email@gmail.com',
             subject: 'Welcome!')
  end
end
```

And here's what my config/application.rb file looks like:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {

        address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
        port:                 587,
        #domain:               'gmail.com',
        user_name:            'example_email@gmail.com',
        password:             'my_password',
        authentication:       'plain',
        enable_starttls_auto: true  

        }

        config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
            :host => "localhost",
            :port => 3000
        }
```

in my config/environments/development.rb file I also have these two lines:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

My problem is that whenever I start the rails console (working in development, have no idea how to run in production), assign a user's email to the user variable then enter the command: `MyMailer.welcome_email(user).deliver`

the terminal says:

```
Rendered my_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb (11.7ms)
  Rendered my_mailer/welcome_email.text.erb (0.5ms)

Sent mail to abhas.arya@yahoo.com (923.1ms)
Date: Fri, 08 Aug 2014 13:54:38 -0400
From: abhas.aryaa@gmail.com
To: abhas.arya@yahoo.com
Message-ID: <53e50ededebb2_2b0b8082dbf8507c5@Abhass-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
Subject: Welcome!
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_53e50eded7355_2b0b8082dbf85068f";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

but then renders the error. My views are simple enough that I didn't think I needed to include them here. I've desperately tried everything, including unlocking google captcha but still nothing works. I'd appreciate any help, all I want is for an email to get sent to the proper inbox. I'd love you forever if you can solve this issue!!!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The reason that you are seeing this error is that Google has blocked your IP. You will need to enable authorization for this IP.

Go to http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click continue.

Then again try to send email from the application, it should work. You will need to send email from your app within 10 min of visiting the above link. By visiting above link, Google will grant access to register new apps for 10 min.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but unfortunately it still doesnt work and shows the exact same errors

Comment: Thank you so much Raj, I followed the link in the error log and temporarily enabled the access to less secure apps and it worked! You rock dude!

Answer (score 5):

I solved by doing the following:

1) Log into the Google Apps Admin portal and enable Less Secure Apps by checking "Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps" under Security preferences.

2) Login into the account that will serve as the mailer and turn "Allow less secure apps" to ON.

Most of the answers available on-line refer to step 2, but you cannot configure at a user level without the Admin turning the feature on.

Comment: I think it necessary to mention that "admin.google.com is used for Google Workspace accounts only. Regular Gmail accounts cannot be used to sign in to admin.google.com"

Answer (score 0):

This one solved the issue for me after some investigation:

Click https://www.google.com/settings/u/0/security/lesssecureapps

Enable access for less secure apps here by logging in with the email address you have provided in smtp configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by doing this.

```
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    domain: 'mysite.com',
    user_name: myemail@gmail.com,
    password: mypassword,
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

As google will try to block your sign-in if you have turned off access for less secure apps in your accounts settings. Therefore, follow this [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and "**Turn on**" access for less secure apps.