# Rails 4 ActionMailer with gmail Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 534-5.7.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, gmail, actionmailer

I am trying to send an email in development version of my app. Nothing I am doing is working. I keep getting hit with: 
**Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 534-5.7.14 https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=blahblahblah**

Other SO posts I have followed:

[Net::SMTPAuthenticationError when sending email from Rails app (on staging environment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir)

[Running into SMTP error when trying to send email in RoR app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209676/running-into-smtp-error-when-trying-to-send-email-in-ror-app)

... etc... and nothing works. I'm going to tear my brains out if can't be resolved. I have spent so long on this...

I have tried going directly to http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click continue, no results. I have already in my google account settings enabled less secure apps access(Google -> Security -> Account permissions -> Access). I have tried going to the link posted after the error, and logged in from there, and no results.

My setup in config/environments/development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    domain: 'mysite.com',
    user_name: ENV['MAIL_EMAIL'],
    password: ENV['MAIL_PASS'],
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

If this makes any difference:

From the apache error logs:

**Warning: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support**

I am hosting two domains on the same IP address.

I switched my rails app to production mode, to see if it would help. No results.

Please help.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this question?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Go to your Google Account settings, find `Security -> Account permissions -> Access for less secure apps`, enable this option.

About this option: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: Yeah I've done it already :( Thanks though for the suggestion

Comment: 1000$ answer. Finally , after 100 attempts I came to know that this silly reason had wasted my 2 weeks.Thanks a ton !!

Comment: @pigate if you've done it already, why did you mark it as the answer?

Comment: Thanks you so much. I started seriously doubting my debugging skills since no effort I was making solved this error.

Comment: Is there a way of solving this that doesn't involving making my app less secure?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works fine for me.

```
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    domain: 'mysite.com',
    user_name: myemail@gmail.com,
    password: mypassword,
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

As google will try to block your sign-in if you have turned off access for less secure apps in your accounts settings. Therefore, follow this [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and "**Turn on**" access for less secure apps.