# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::PasswordsController#create when working with devise mailers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am implementing devise mailers for my application where i have done the following steps:

in model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

and then I added migrations of *confirmation_token, confirmed_at,
confirmation_sent_at*

In devise.rb, I added:

```
  config.mailer_sender = 'example@gmail.com'
  #config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'
```

In development.rb:

```
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => "mail.google.com",
      :user_name => "example@gmail.com",
      :password => "somepassword",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

everything working fine. But the email is not generated.
In my console i am getting mail information and link..

my console:

```
Sent mail to example@yahoo.com (2597.8ms)
Date: Wed, 08 Apr 2015 23:39:09 +0530
From: example@gmail.com
Reply-To: example@gmail.com
To: example@yahoo.com
Message-ID: <55256ec5ba47e_26f51d984dc117aa@itadmin-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC.mail>
Subject: Reset password instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hello exmple@yahoo.com!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=M5os3tBYHQrsRaw4TtTt">Change my password</a></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```

I haven't added any devise passwords controller / registartion controllers.
I am getting a error when i click on Forgot password and enter email and click on "Send me reset password instructions" button.
this is the error, i am getting:

**Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::PasswordsController#create**

***`534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsrrD`-***

I used [Running into SMTP error when trying to send email in RoR app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209676/running-into-smtp-error-when-trying-to-send-email-in-ror-app) but didn't helped me.
What might me the problem?

Comment: Seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209676/running-into-smtp-error-when-trying-to-send-email-in-ror-app

Comment: I have answered similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25209735/1047207

Answer (score 6):

After checking some options in google, this one works

Click https://www.google.com/settings/u/0/security/lesssecureapps

Enable access for less secure apps here by logging in with the email address you have provided in smtp configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Login into your google account, find "Allow less secure apps" and turn it to ON.