# Mail to all user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I want to send a mail to all my users when an article is published. I have this code :

**Mailer class**

```
class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer
 def notification_mail(user)
   @user = user
   mail(to: @user.email, subject: '**TEST**')
 end
end
```

**Article.rb**

```
after_create :send_email_to_users    
def send_email_to_users
   User.all.each do |user|
     AdminMailer.notification_mail(user).deliver_now    
   end
end
```

**Configuration**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'simon.m@********.com',
  :password => '********',
  :address => 'smtp.*******.com',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

This code seems to work because when I post an article I can see on my console that e-mail are send but I didn't receive them into my mailbox.

**CONSOLE**

```
AdminMailer#notification_mail: processed outbound mail in 23.1ms

Sent mail to simon.m@*******.fr (30014.1ms)
Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2015 05:21:05 -0700
From: simon.m@******.com
To: simon.m@*********.fr
Message-ID: <557588b117179_ae53f7fcf56e0d0328b8@localhost.localdomain.mail>
Subject: **TEST**
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_557588b114e80_ae53f7fcf56e0d0327be";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_557588b114e80_ae53f7fcf56e0d0327be
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VW5lIGlkw6llIHZpZW50IGQnw6p0cmUgcHVibGnDqWUKPT09PT09PT09PT09
PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT0K

----==_mimepart_557588b114e80_ae53f7fcf56e0d0327be
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content=3D'text/html; charset=3DUTF-8' http-equiv=3D'Content-Ty=
pe' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Une id=C3=A9e vient d'=C3=AAtre publi=C3=A9e </h1>
  </body>
</html>

  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone know how to make it works ?

Comment: please check your spam folder.

Comment: Can you show your ActionMailer configuration? (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration)

Comment: I've checked every folder in my box, I tried to use fake e-mail, but not working too ...
I've updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have deliveries and delivery errors enabled for the environment your app is running in.

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Last time I did this I had to enable less secure apps on my google apps account, it might be the same for you. It's hard to say without any errors. Visit https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps to enable that. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir)

Make sure Google hasn't blocked your IP. Go to http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click continue.
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209676/running-into-smtp-error-when-trying-to-send-email-in-ror-app)

Seeing some sort of error would help to narrow this down but hopefully this helps!