# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.) Openshift production only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift, actionmailer

I'm trying to send an email through gmail/actionmailer, it works perfectly on my local development box, but when I try and run the same code on production server it gives me an `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.`.  I think this is because gmail is rejecting my login credentials from an unknown server.But I'm not sure!  How do I fix it?

### Background:

I am using the [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem, and I am setting my environment variables on the openshift server with: `rhc set-env`.  I've checked that the environment variables are set on the server.

The questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941692/rails-4-actionmailer-with-gmail-netsmtpauthenticationerror-534-5-7-14?lq=1), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209676/running-into-smtp-error-when-trying-to-send-email-in-ror-app) are all good, but have not done anything to solve my problem. My problem is a bit different because it only shows up on my server, everything works fine on my local box.

**Development:**

In development mode, I have the figaro gem installed, and I have my configuration file stored in application.yml which is *not* checked into git.
Here are it's contents:

```
## config/application.yml
# Add configuration values here, as shown below.

gmail_username: 'PLACE_HOLDER_EMAIL@gmail.com'
gmail_password: 'PLACE_HOLDER_PASSWORD'
```

In my controller:

```
## PLACEHOLDER_controller.rb
 def create
    @placeholder = Placeholder.new(placeholder_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @placeholder.save

        puts "SENDING..."
        puts "Sending to: #{ENV['gmail_username']}..."
        PLACEHOLDERMailer.placeholder_email(some, params).deliver         
        puts "SENT!"
    end
  end
```

**Production:**

```
   ## /config/environments/production.rb
  # SMTP                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # SMTP settings for gmail                                                                                                                                                                                        
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :user_name            => "#{ENV['gmail_username']}",
    :password             => "#{ENV['gmail_password']}",
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

**Production:**

I push the code to my OpenShift repo with git, the server restarts, ostensibly everything is fine.  Except that when I create a new placeholder, I get a 500 back from the server.

Here is the log output:

```
>> rhc tail -a MY_APP
 SENDING...
Sending to: "PLACE_HOLDER_EMAIL@gmail.com"... ## This is the correct email! It's clearly pulling the proper values from ENV.
INFO -- :   Rendered placeholder_mailer/placeholder_email.text.erb (0.1ms)
INFO -- : 
Sent mail to 9739069711@txt.att.net (132.3ms)
INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 224ms
FATAL -- : 
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
 ):
 app/controllers/placeholders_controller.rb:35:in `block in create'
app/controllers/placeholders_controller.rb:29:in `create'
```

Which says that the username and password were not accepted.  Now, I know that I have the correct username and password.  I'm fairly certain that's not the issue.  I suspect that (as mentioned in the linked questions) smtp.gmail.com is rejecting my login from an unknown server.

#### Before anyone suggests it, I have already:

- [Disabled Two Factor Authentication](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1064203?hl=en)
- Tried [creating an application specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) and using that instead. (Didn't work, I've now switched back to the regular account password)
- [Enabled access to less secure applications.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

#### TL;DR

I'm trying to send an email from the server. When I run it on the server it gives me: `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.`.  I think this is because gmail is rejecting my login credentials from an unknown server.  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out [Gmail blocks you temporarily](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257) if you try to access it programmatically more than once every ten minutes. This was a rate limiting issue.

Comment: good on you for answering your own cold storage question :)